# What is the smallest environment size that allows to represent every quantum channel in fixed dimensions?

Tags: quantum-operation

From the Stinespring dilation, we have that the dual or complementary channel can be observed in/expressed with the environment.

Can we reconstruct any channel for environments with $\text{dim}>1$ or does the dimension need to be higher? Also, how would one go forward with doing so?

Comment: what do you mean with "the complementary channel can be expressed with the environment"? Stinespring's dilation just tells you that any channel can be described as a unitary/isometric evolution in a larger space, ie $\Phi(\rho)=\operatorname{tr}_2[V\rho V^\dagger]$, and that the complementary channel can be described via the same isometric evolution by looking at the "environment output", ie $\Phi^c(\rho)=\operatorname{tr}_1[V\rho V^\dagger]$.

Comment: To reformulate: what is the minimal dimention of the environment  so that we can represent every quantum channel for a fixed Euclidean space?

Answer (score 4):

If a completely positive map $\Phi$ sends states in $\mathbb{C}^n$ to states in $\mathbb{C}^m$, then its Choi is a linear operator acting in an $nm$-dimensional space, and thus its maximum possible rank is $nm$. The rank of the Choi corresponds to the minimum number of Kraus operators needed to represent $\Phi$, which in turn corresponds to the minimal dimension of the environment to represent $\Phi$ via Stinespring dilation. See for example the first part of [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/24522/55), and the links there, for more details on why this is so.

It follows that all completely positive maps of this form can be represented using an environment of dimension $nm$.

Comment: Moreover, $mn$ is the smallest number which works for **all** channels because one can easily construct channels such that the Choi matrix has rank $mn$. The simplest example is, arguably, the unital reset channel $X\mapsto {\rm tr}(X)\frac{{\bf1}_m}m$ as its Choi matrix equals $\frac{{\bf1}_{mn}}{m}$